# How to get rid of empty space caused by deleted QListWidgetItems in a QlistWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

I have a QlistWidget with customWidgets inside. Each of them include a delete button for themselves which is connected to the parent MainWindow class via Slot/Signal.
I can delete such a customWidget but the problem is, the space it has occupied before is still there (like a gap) between the other customWidgets. I haven't found anything so far to really get rid of it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can we see a small example? I have not experienced this before.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found something: removeItemWidget() removes the item visually but not the count() of QListWidget.

so really delete it, one has to to delete on the Pointer of the QListWidgetItem, only then the visual space will be freed, too.